# How to git list all tracked and untracked files created/updated/deleted/renamed since main, including filenames before and after rename?

Tags: git

I need to git list all untracked files, and all tracked files which have been created, updated, deleted and renamed since main.
For renamed files, I need the file name before rename and after rename.
Ideally the output should be just a list of file paths split by new lines, such as the output of `git diff --name-only`

Thanks

I currently managed to achieve 80% this through the use of multiple commands:
`git diff --name-only --cached` - get staged created/updated/delete/renamed files. However, for renames this only gives the filename after the rename.
`git diff --name-only main` - get already commited created/updated/deleted/renamed files.
`git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` - get untracked files.

What I'm still missing is listing the renamed filenames before the rename

Comment: You can't show deletion of untracked files. They are gone from the filesystem and leave no trace in git history. Similarly for modification, there's only the current state and no history to compare it to.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm still missing is listing the renamed filenames before the rename

Maybe something like this would list all renamed file, with their old and new name:

```bash
git log  --diff-filter=R main | grep renamed | \
sed 's|^.*renamed:[^a-zA-Z]*\(.*\) -> \(.*\)$|\1 -> \2|'
```